# How can i make an immutable subclass of a superclass with final setter methods?

Tags: java, scala, class, inheritance, immutability

I would like to create an immutable scala class, but I also want to extend a java superclass with final setters.

Is this possible and if not, what would be the best (most similar to extending) work-around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you can't override a final method, it means that even if you found some tricks to extends it (by for example, using another method signature or delegating the call), you still will have a "public final" setter method which can be used by your clients, in your Immutable class. Which is I think a big flaw since your Immutability won't be preserved in all cases.

I would suggest to define a new Class which does not extends from the Mutable one but delegates some operation to it, only the ones that does not create mutability.

It's often like this it's implemented in Java or in libraries like Guava, we create a private inner field of the mutable object, and we expose only publicly methods that won't alter the list itself.

Comment: Not extending, but delegating operation to a private inner field, means the subclass cant be passed as an argument to certain methods. I then will have to expose the private inner field with a getter as late as possible, but that still violates immutability. But probably going for this anyway, if there is no better option